# How to browserify a standalone module for use in WebWorkers

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, web-worker, browserify, lodash

I am using browserify to create standalone modules that I can use in node.js and client side in browser. I don't use browserify on the entire app, just a few single node modules.

I do browserify-shim to shim e.g. `lodash` under the global `var` `_`.
This works very well except when using the modules inside webworkers.

**The problem is:**

When I shim `lodash` as `_` the browserified code sets `var _ = window._`,
but windows is not defined inside the web workers.

**My setup**

I use grunt to browserify, and have browserify-shim configured in my package.json

***map.js:*** (commonJS module, used directly in node.js)

```
var _ = require('lodash-node');

module.exports = _.map;
```

***GruntFile.js:***

```
// Browserify
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-browserify');

grunt.initConfig({
    browserify: {
        'map': {
            options: {
                bundleOptions: {
                    standalone: 'MapModule'
                }
            },
            src: ['./map.js'],
            dest: './output/map-module.js'
        }
    }
});

grunt.registerTask('default', [
    'browserify'
]);
```

***package.json:***(partial)

```
{
    "name": "APP NAME",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "app.js",
    "browserify": {
        "transform": [
            "browserify-shim"
        ]
    },
    "browserify-shim": {
        "lodash-node": "global:_"
    },
}
```

**The output**

the generated output from browserify looks like this:
https://gist.github.com/mikaelhm/859735472c9b0038770e

Note line 2: `var _ = (window._);`

Thats a problem in a Web Worker.

**Am I doing it all wrong, or is it only supposed to work in normal browsing mode?**

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post but I'm sharing the solution I found as this took me a few hours to find a solution.

I managed to get web workers running as modules using
https://github.com/substack/webworkify it's avaliable as via npm install webworkify.

A task I had to perform inside my web worker was to parse an xml string to javascript this I did with xmldoc, as xmldoc does not require a DOM and there is no DOM in web workers.

I include xmldoc in my web worker with require, which would be the same for lodash.

Comment: In order to make a good answer, you should provide a code example of how you use webworkify to solve your problem.